# agrupar resultados por "componente" y a la vez por su última modificación

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT id,componente,detalles,estado,usuario_insert,usuario_insert_copia,ubicacion,
usu1_apellido,usu1_nombre,usu2_apellido,usu2_nombre,fechaInsert,fechaUpdate
FROM View_Novedades  WHERE eliminado=0 AND fk_idTipo='3' 
order by CASE WHEN fechaUpdate IS null THEN fechaInsert 
else fechaUpdate end DESC, estado, componente
```

[image: ne]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona el sitio y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado.

Comment: Si vas a agrupar por esas columnas, qué quieres poner en el resto de las columnas?, por ejemplo en "detalle"?

Comment: solo necesito que me quede ordenada por componente y ese mismo orden por ultima modificación

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Agrupados por componente

Agregas la siguiente linea para agregar por componente

```
GROUP BY componente
```

Queda así:

```
SELECT id,componente,detalles,estado,usuario_insert,usuario_insert_copia,ubicacion,
usu1_apellido,usu1_nombre,usu2_apellido,usu2_nombre,fechaInsert,fechaUpdate
FROM View_Novedades  
WHERE eliminado=0 AND fk_idTipo='3' 
GROUP BY componente 
order by CASE WHEN fechaUpdate IS null THEN fechaInsert 
else fechaUpdate end DESC, estado, componente
```

Si también quieres agrupar por fecha de ultima modificación, que asumo que te refieres a la columna fechaUpdate, simplemente lo agregas al group by de la siguiente manera:

```
GROUP BY componente, fechaUpdate
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [answer]. Te recomiendo también que elimines el primer comentario de tu respuesta, ya que no agrega nada a la respuesta en sí.

Comment: Tu no tienes que entender nada, aquí se responden a dudas que tienen los usuarios, por cierto tu respuesta es incorrecta el group by no se usa así

Comment: esto es SQL Server, no puedes simplemente agrupar por una columna y no poner una función de agregación en el resto de las columnas del `SELECT`. Esto va a lanzar error

Comment: O sea que al fin y al cabo él no sabía usar un Group By?